# "=" not finding match for exact database value in MySQL, but LIKE works

Tags: mysql, database

I am not able to select from my adSpec table where the width value matches exactly, for a specific value. This does not happen for all cells within the column.

**My adSpec Table**

```
╔═══════════╦══════════════╗
║  adSpecId ║     width    ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════╣
║    100    ║   154.00800  ║
║    101    ║   319.96799  ║
║    102    ║   342.00000  ║
║    103    ║   342.00000  ║
╚═══════════╩══════════════╝
```

**Does NOT return result**

```
SELECT * FROM `adSpec` where `width` = '154.00800'
```

**DOES return result**

```
SELECT * FROM `adSpec` where `width` LIKE '154.00800'
```

**Using "=" even works with other values in the same column**

```
SELECT * FROM `adSpec` where `width` = '319.96799'
```

---

Note: There are no trailing spaces after the value within the db

---

**Width Column Details**

Type: float

Length: 10

Decimals: 5

Comment: Make sure you don't have white space in your records

Comment: please show the datatype of width column

Comment: added details for width column @RachidB.

Comment: Length and decimals will only affect the format of floats when displayed. See @dylan's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FLOAT is not reliable for precise comparison.

## Quote:

Because floating-point values are approximate and not stored as exact values, attempts to treat them as exact in comparisons may lead to problems. They are also subject to platform or implementation dependencies. For more information, see Section B.5.4.8, “Problems with Floating-Point Values”
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html

Here is a demo on the unreliability:

```
mysql> create table adSpec(adSpecId int, width float(10,5));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into adSpec values(100,154.00800);
select *,Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select *, round(width, 20), width = '154.00800' from adSpec;
+----------+-----------+--------------------------+---------------------+
| adSpecId | width     | round(width, 20)         | width = '154.00800' |
+----------+-----------+--------------------------+---------------------+
|      100 | 154.00800 | 154.00799560546875000000 |                   0 |
+----------+-----------+--------------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you want to do exact comparison, try decimal.

DECIMAL:

```
mysql> create table adSpec(adSpecId int, width decimal(10,5));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into adSpec values(100,154.00800);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select *, round(width, 20), width = '154.00800' from adSpec;
+----------+-----------+--------------------------+---------------------+
| adSpecId | width     | round(width, 20)         | width = '154.00800' |
+----------+-----------+--------------------------+---------------------+
|      100 | 154.00800 | 154.00800000000000000000 |                   1 |
+----------+-----------+--------------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check for any white space on your database. If you are inserting in to your Database from a program use the functionality available to trim before inserting that way you should be able to get the exact search results based on your criteria.
2. Make sure the to use like with '' and if the Data type column is number you can use = with out any ''

Answer (score 0):

A decimal(10,3) will have only 3 decimal places and can be compared in the same manner as integers.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html